# pycharm connect to ssh via proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, pycharm

I am trying to run my code using ssh interpreter in pycharm.

I have a server behind a proxy.
I set up my .ssh/config file like so

```
Host bastion
   Hostname bastion_ip
   Port 22
   User username

Host server
   Hostname server_ip
   User username
   ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W %h:%p
```

In addition I tried to create ssh interpreter in pycharm
here is my configuaration
[image]

Yet I am not able to connect to the server (pycharm doesn't finish trying to connect)

Why cant I connect to the server?

UPDATE: I think the problem is because I need to enter the password twice (for the first connection and for the jump) any idea on how to deal with that?

Comment: Have you gained any new insights on that issue?

Comment: sadly, no. I have tried many combination but it seems like pycharm simply does not support it